# Laravel: Mail send not working

Tags: laravel-5.1, sendmail

If i do this in Laravel 5.1

```
Route::get('test_email', function(){
  Mail::raw(
        "",
        function ($mail) {
            $mail->from('info@test.com');
            $mail->to('test@test.com', 'test');
         }
   );
});
```

The email is sent to *MAIL_TO_ADDRESS* set into *.env*. It ignore the *to* value.
Why?

Comment: I resolve. See [Universal To](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
Mail::send('', array(), function($mail) {
  $mail->to('example@example.com', 'full_name')->from('example@example.com')->subject('Mail');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

\Mail::send('view_name', [array of parameters for sending them to view file], function($mail) {
  $mail->to('example@example.com', 'full_name')->from('example@example.com')->subject('Mail');
});

You have to use "log" as MAIL_DRIVER.

You can set the above mail configuration in config/mail.php

Mail will be logged to the log file you can open log file at storage/logs and you can see the mail in it.